# How to not run an example using roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm writing a [geocoding function](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo/blob/master/R/Contributed.R) right now that relies on having a Bing Maps Key.  Obviously I'd rather not publish mine, and the examples fail without one.

How do I include an example for users to run manually, but not have it executed during `R CMD check`?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Use `\dontrun{}`

```
#'@examples
#'\dontrun{
#'geocode("3817 Spruce St, Philadelphia, PA 19104")
#'geocode("Philadelphia, PA")
#'dat <- data.frame(value=runif(3),address=c("3817 Spruce St, Philadelphia, PA 19104","Philadelphia, PA","Neverneverland"))
#'geocode(dat)
#'}
```

Comment: this is documented in `?example` and [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions)

Comment: @Jeroen, I believe that `roxygen2` made up the `@example` tag, so I think it's an `roxygen2` problem.  I don't think `\example{}` is valid -- see http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#index-g_t_005cexamples-78

Comment: Judging from the topic title, the question is about roxygen2 syntax and not about .Rd syntax?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't work for me first because I was using `@example` instead of `@examples`. Both tags come up in RStudio auto-complete. I'm happy now.

Comment: using `@example`, you can still use `dontrun{}` inside the example file. formatting multiline code in comments doesn't work well, so see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32888259/1380598) on the related question.

Comment: I think the correct answer for what is being asked for is donttest and not dontrun. See ?example and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038160/how-to-not-run-an-example-using-roxygen2#comment89039795_44997778. See also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html.

Answer (score 49):

You can use `\donttest{}` to your example. The snippet will be provided in your documentation, but won't get tested with the R CMD Check.

For more info --> `?example`

```
#' @example
\donttest{
    2^2
    }
```

This 2^2 won't get run when you run `devtools::check()`

---

**EDIT**

Per the latest release notes or [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) for *R 4.0.0*, examples within `\donttest{}` will now be tested by default. This can, however, be overridden by setting environment variable `_R_CHECK_DONTTEST_EXAMPLES_` to `FALSE`.

> R CMD check --as-cran now runs \donttest examples (which are run by example()) instead of instructing the tester to do so. This can be temporarily circumvented during development by setting environment variable *R_CHECK_DONTTEST_EXAMPLES* to a false value.

According to [this](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2216) GitHub issues discussion (credited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693563/issues-in-r-package-after-cran-asked-to-replace-dontrun-by-donttest)), Hadley Wickham noted that

> Generally, now if you don't want to run tests on CRAN \dontrun{} is more likely to work, but using \dontrun{} may cause initial submission to fail.

There are other ways as well that will let you continue to use `donttest{}`, refer the aforementioned discussions for the workarounds.

Comment: It seems that this should be the accepted answer instead of dontrun. From ?example 'donttest
encloses code that typically should be run, but not during package checking.' whereas 'dontrun
encloses code that should not be run.' I also got a comment by cran maintainers to switch from dontrun to donttest.

Comment: Totally agree with @JulianKarls. Got the same feedback from CRAN maintainers.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are using `@example path/to/example.R` instead of the `@examples` tag you can use the `\dontrun` environment directly in the `example.R` file.  For example

```
# example.R
\dontrun{
# this is a long running example
for(i in seq(1, 1e5)) { lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars) }
}

# some other shorter example
2 + 2
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me (running on Win 10, 64 bit, R version 3.5.0)

Answer (score 4):

```
\dontrun{}
```

Is the correct function. See here:

> For the purpose of illustration, it’s often useful to include code that causes an error. \dontrun{} allows you to include code in the example that is not run. (You used to be able to use \donttest{} for a similar purpose, but it’s no longer recommended because it actually is tested.)

Source: https://r-pkgs.org/man.html?q=donttest#man-functions

Comment: This answer was already given and accepted. The link is not worth an answer, it is a comment

Answer (score 3):

Ari, I also use roxygen2 (version 4.1.0). The following is the end of my roxygen2 mark-up in my function (gctemplate) definition till the beginning of the real part.

```
#' @examples
#' ## List all G-causalities in a VAR system of 5 variables that will be searched in the pattern of 1 
#' ## causer (like-independent) variable and 2 like-dependents conditional on 5-(1+2)=2 of the remaining 
#' ## variable(s) in the system. Variables are assigned to numbers 1 to nvars. 
#' ## "1 2 5 3 4" in the resulting line of gctemplate is to indicate the 
#' ## (conditonal, partial, etc.) G-causality from variable 1 to variables 2 and 5 
#' ## conditonal on variables 3 and 4.
#' # gctemplate(5,1,2)
#' ## The number of all G-causalities to be searched in the above pattern.
#' #dim(gctemplate(5,1,2))[[1]]
#' @importFrom combinat combn
#' @export
gctemplate <- function(nvars, ncausers, ndependents){
...
```

I know GSee's dontrun method.
In my technique, the numerical example and the text explaining the numerical example are both comments. I use indentation to make difference between these two; Notice there are 1 sharp and 2 sharps respectively after "#'". I always use the above "#' ## / #' #" technique in my packages. The user is left to copy-paste operation whenever s/he wanna test the function. This technique is - according to me - more parallel with the classical comment bombardment of the software coding philosophy.

Comment: If you use `dontrun{}`, then the user can call `example(myFunction, run.dontrun=TRUE)`, whereas if you simply comment out the examples, you have no way to run the examples other than to copy/paste.