# R package examples run on Mac but not Windows ("assign" error)

Tags: r, package, cran

My R package ([git repository](https://github.com/mayamathur/NRejections/blob/master/NRejections/R/NRejections.R)) passes `devtools::build` locally on my Mac, but the CRAN incoming checks indicate that two of the examples fail on Windows and Linux with the following error:

```
ERROR
Running examples in 'NRejections-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
```

Strangely, this same package had previously passed checks and been uploaded to CRAN, but I recently got an email saying that it is no longer passing these checks on other platforms.

There was [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117334/baseassign-ptime-proc-time-pos-checkexenv-error-when-using-devtool) about the same error message, but there it seems the error was inherent to the examples and not platform-dependent.

Comment: What version of R are you running locally? It's possible CRAN is using a version with more aggressive checks. What you run locally isn't always exactly the same as what's run on their servers. It would be better to provide a minimal reproducible example in your question rather than just linking to your entire package.

Comment: I'll try updating R. Not sure how to create a MWE in this case since it would presumably involve creating a fake package, uploading it to CRAN, and hoping it fails the CRAN checks.

Comment: @MrFlick was right -- I had to update R locally in order to reproduce the failing CRAN checks locally. Thanks!