# R function example requires nonstandard dataset, doesn't jive with devtools

Tags: r, github, documentation, devtools, r-package

I've been struggling to get the example code for a function working using `devtools::check()`, because the data required for the example is not in .RData format.  Unfortunately, the way the function is written, .RData cannot be loaded and work properly.  The function takes in a list of filenames and performs an action on them collectively.

Therefore, example code must be written in a way that `check()` is able to access a folder and list the files therein.  Using the function on my own computer, I input

```
setwd("/Users/mydirectory")
myfilelist <- list.files(pattern = "mypattern")
output <- myfunction(myfilelist, ...)
```

and everything is groovy.  But this doesn't work with `devtools` because `@examples` doesn't know how to access subdirectories on my computer.  `check()` pulls the following error:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")

This is almost undoubtedly because `check()` doesn't know where to look for the data.  I'd like it to look toward github to access the online data repository.

I found [this brief conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117334/baseassign-ptime-proc-time-pos-checkexenv-error-when-using-devtool) regarding a similar `roxygen`-related problem, but overall I haven't seen much advice on how to work through it.  I think that perhaps [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684026/check-new-r-package) starts to get a little closer to my situation, but here the user failed to export a function, rather than bind data to an example.

I don't think I'm looking for a pull function (though the end goal is to pull data...), does anyone have advice moving forward?  I have the data stored in the inst/extdata folder on [github](https://github.com/JepsonNomad/phenocosm), so while I don't really have something reproducible for you all I'm hoping you might have some thoughts.

**Edit**:  I worked around the problem using @alistaire's advice below, and guiding the `roxygen` to the package directory (updated on github) and also using `\dontrun{}`.  However, I am leaving the question unanswered for now because I think accessing data stored in github should still be somehow possible and we haven't yet addressed that.

Comment: Totes diggin the use of "jive" in the question title. Somewhat more seriously, is the loading of the data necessary, or could you just put it in `.rbuildignore` or something like that?

Comment: @RobertMc Does `.rbuildignore` skip processing of the example when using `check()`?  If so, will that impact the possibility of submitting to CRAN?  As I understand, errors pulled in `check()` pretty much eliminate acceptance by CRAN.

Comment: Sounds like some version of `list.files(system.file('misc', package = 'utils'))`, but more context is necessary. Or just set the example so it doesn't run and ignore the issue.